# constructing url dynamically

Tags: asp.net, .net, hyperlink

i tried to construct url in asp.net like this

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="edit" runat="server" NavigateUrl="./edit.aspx/&action=edit&id=<%#Eval("id")%>">Edit</asp:HyperLink>
```

but i get an error when i run the asp.net page

> Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 71:  ">Edit
>
> Source File: /admin/vehicle/view.aspx    Line: 71

can anyone help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="edit" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "./Edit.aspx/action=edit&id=" & Server.UrlEncode(Container.DataItem("MyID"))%>'/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the "~/" so that it will resolve as root sites and virtual directories:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="edit" runat="server" 
   NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/edit.aspx/&action=edit&id={0}",Eval("id"))%>'>Edit</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: "~/" points to site root directory, instead of current directory